# Как получить сессию по ее идентификатору

Tags: php, авторизация, сессия

Всем привет!
Кто может подсказать способ прочитать данные сессии, имея только куку с PHPSESSID?.
PHPSESSID приходит от другого обработчика сессий на другом движке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

просто

```
session_id($phpsessionId);
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает!